# NSOpenPanel does not allow multiple selection of symbolic links

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

In a MacOS app I am using [`NSOpenPanel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel?language=objc) so that the user can browse and select multiple images as follows:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
panel.canChooseDirectories = NO;
panel.canChooseFiles = YES;
panel.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
panel.resolvesAliases = YES;
panel.allowedFileTypes = [NSImage imageTypes];
panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSModalResponse result) {
    ...
```

This works just fine except when the files are symbolic links (left image below), but the user can only select a single image when symbolic links are used (right image below):

[image]
[image]

The files in the `images-A` folder are symbolic links:

[image]

There are some older related questions:

- [How to NOT resolve symbolic links in NSOpenPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408075/how-to-not-resolve-symbolic-links-in-nsopenpanel)
- [Why can I select aliases but not symbolic links in NSOpenPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190818/why-can-i-select-aliases-but-not-symbolic-links-in-nsopenpanel)

I am not using aliases here, and I don't care how the path is resolved.
Any idea how to allow selection of multiple links with `NSOpenPanel`?